# Is there any way to make FileUtils work with UTF-8 file names?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.2

I have created this Ruby (1.9.2) code and the last line fails:

```
File.open("test äöü.txt", "w+").close
File.chmod(0644, "test äöü.txt")
FileUtils.chmod(0644, "test äöü.txt") # FAILS
```

The message is:

> Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - C:/.../test ├ñ├Â├╝.txt):

Althoug the `FileUtil.chmod` calls `File.chmod` eventually, for some reason it messes with the file name along the way.

Normally I'd just use `File` instead of `FileUtils`, but unfortunately I'm using a gem which uses `FileUtils` and I'm hoping I can avoid changing the gem source.

Does anyone know why this is happening? The source of `FileUtils.chmod` looks straightforward but I still can't figure out the problem. Is there any way to monkey-patch `FileUtils` to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your `ruby -v`? No problem for me on OS X with `ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]`; seems like a Windows-only bug.

Comment: It's `ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a Windows only problem, related to [issue 1685](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/1685).

Hopefully someone with a good understanding of encoding issues & windows can enlighten you as to what can be done until it is resolved.

Comment: It seems that `File.path` has something to do with this: `File.path("test äöü.txt")` returns `"test ├ñ├Â├╝.txt"`. (And since `FileUtils.chmod` is using `File.path`...)